# How to make session in Java?

Tags: java, web-applications

I need make sessions in Java web application.
I found that sesstion makes in servlet calass by method `getSession()`.
But i have a question about session parameters. For example i send to server login/pass and save it into session atributes. Okey. Next time i do something on client and send new params to server. Where i gonna send it? In another or same and i gonna use `if else` for handle params like this?

[image]
Another question: How to use params which i put in session(login/pass) in another classes?

**UPDATE**

I read about [sessions](http://www.developer.com/java/using-the-httpsession-object-of-the-servlet-api.html). And have new question. How to use session params in enother class. I mean after login i send new params on server, read it in servlet and want to take a login/pass from session and send it with new params into another class.

Comment: If you have a new question it's usually better to post it in, well, a new question :) That makes it easier for other users to discover and understand your questions and answers.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner: Sorry. Okey. But i was thought that question abou same problem better combine in one tread. But okey i create new)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As  part of your request handling in a doGet or doPost method, here is how you can get session and use it to get and set variables.

```
//Obtain the session object, create a new session if doesn't exist
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

//set a string session attribute
session.setAttribute("MySessionVariable", "MySessionAtrValue");

//get a string sessson attribute
String strParam = session.getAttribute("MySessionVariable");


//get an integer sessioin attribute
Integer param = (Integer) session.getAttribute("MySessionVariable");

//set an integer session attribute
session.setAttribute("MySessionVariable", new Integer(param.intValue() + 1));
```

Comment: The session will be created when user access to the first view of the web application...

Comment: So when after creating session i send another params to this servlet again session will not created?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: That isin't true if all the jsp has `<%@ page session="false" %>`.

Comment: @Ankit: i have not this parameter in my jsp.

Comment: @KliverMax please read [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) and [Using the HttpSession object of the Servlet API](http://www.developer.com/java/using-the-httpsession-object-of-the-servlet-api.html).

Comment: So session will be created on first access of your web application. You can use session as in the answer above.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: Thanks for links)

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza:I read your seccond link its nice. But now i have a new question. I update question please look at it)

Answer (score 0):

`Session` is associated with each request . Now it depends whether client join the session or not there are three overloaded methods of `getSession()` to get more about them please go through the [documents](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). Now if session is aleady associated with the request get existing session set the attribute in session and vice-versa if not create new session and do the same.

`if the server used only cookie-based sessions, and the client had disabled the use of cookies, then a session would be new on each request.`

I hope this helped.

Comment: *Session is associated with each request* that's completely false. The session has a longer live than a simple request. The fact that you can access to the client session using the request ease the programming model, that's all.

Comment: I dont agree with you . It depends .. whether new session or old session.if the server used cookie-based sessions and cookies are enabled on client machine then same session will be associated with each new request.

Comment: Based on what you said, two requests can share the same session. That's perfect since *the session has a longer live than a simple request*.

Comment: By the way, if you post a real world example of your last update, it would be great.

Comment: Right . But if client disables the cookies then on each request there would be a new session.

Comment: Again, provide a real world example of a live application server that only uses cookie-based sessions (or a web application which app server does this). If you do this, I'll regret my comments.

Comment: When container gets a request but with no JSESSIONID cookie (cookies disabled client) then container creates a new session when request.getSession() is called . Session is basically shared by JSESSIONID cookie

Comment: Yeah examples will nice. I will glad to more and more examples)

Comment: "Session is associated with each request" is not quite true. "Session *may be* associated with each request" is true, but unusual in practice. Usually if cookies are disabled a framework will fall back to putting session tokens into hidden fields or something similar.

Comment: Session management is done by multiple ways however one of them is session . URL Re-writing , cookies,HTML form etc and almost every Application server uses cookies to manage HTTP Session.http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_StateManagement.html